# How to replace multiple # with values from an array?

Tags: php, replace

I'm not exactly sure what this is called but is common in programming, often using the ? instead of the % which I use in this example.

Say I have a string:

> "How many % does it take the build a % out of aluminum cans?"

And I want to replace the **%** symbol with specific values from an array based on their index and the position in the string. In this case:

```
['robots', 'laser gun']
```

The result would be:

> How many *robots* does it take to build a *laser gun* out of aluminum cans?

Is there any way to easily accomplish this in PHP?

Comment: Well, check out [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.sprintf.php).

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping out. the vsprintf() solution worked best for what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just adding to the options :-)

```
<?php

$s=    "How many  %1\$s does it take the build a  %2\$s out of aluminum cans?";
$a=array('robots', 'laser gun');

echo vsprintf($s,$a)
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this up and tested it, works!

```
$randomstring = "How many % does it take the build a % out of aluminum cans?";

$array = array("robots", "laser gun");

for($x = 0;$x != count($array);$x++){
   $randomstring = preg_replace('/%/', $array[$x], $randomstring, 1);
}

echo $randomstring;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
sprintf ( "How many %s does it take the build a %s out of aluminum cans?", "robots", "laser gun" )
```

[sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 0):

The following code does the job:

```
$string = 'How many % does it take the build a % out of aluminum cans?';
$placeholders = ['robots', 'laser gun'];
echo call_user_func_array('sprintf', array_merge([str_replace('%', '%s', $string)], $placeholders));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you label the tokens then you can use `strtr` to search and replace the values. Using named tokens makes your code slightly easier to read.

```
$str = "How many {thing} does it take the build a {weapon} out of aluminum cans?";

echo strtr($str, [
    '{thing}'  => 'robots',
    '{weapon}' => 'laser gun',
]);
```